# How to put 2 javascript items on 1 line?

Tags: javascript, css, dom, output

I've been creating a JS website where it tells you your age in days. I wrote the code, so that, if you were born before 1990, the website says "Yikes you're old". I styled that text apart from the other text but the output was on another line. I want to bring both texts on the same line. I don't know how to do that, so your help is greatly appreciated. Here's the JS code:

```
function ageInDays() {
  // variables
    var birthYear = prompt("What Year Were You Born In?");
    var ageInDayss = (2021 - birthYear) * 365;

  //text

    if (birthYear>1990) {
        var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
        var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDayss + " days 
        old.");
        h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
        h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
        document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1);

   } else {
       var h1 = document.createElement('h1');
       var h2 = document.createElement('h2');
       var textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are " + ageInDayss + " days old.");
       var textAnswer1 = document.createTextNode(" Yikes... that's old.");
       h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
       h2.setAttribute('id', 'yikes');
       h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
       h2.appendChild(textAnswer1);
       document.getElementById('flex-box-result').appendChild(h1).appendChild(h2);
    }


}
```

How do I bring the "else" output on one line?

Comment: How would you do it if this was _not_ dynamically created, but _static_ HTML written directly in the text editor? That's the same way you do it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does in need to be explicitly h1 and h2? They are block elements by default and is not really a good practice to use an element for something else (using it inline) than it was created for.

I'd recommend using span

```
...
var text1 = document.createElement('span');
var text2 = document.createElement('span');
...
```

and styling it accordingly.

Comment: tysm man. It worked

Comment: Happy to help. More about the topic: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp . It seems you might be looking for some tutorial materials, you might like [free code camp](https://www.freecodecamp.org/).

Comment: ok, thanks. Also, I have another quesiton. It'd be great if you could answer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70316406/vertically-aligning-parent-divs-in-css